# How to get First Day and last day of the week of a date

Tags: android

I am using DatePickerDialog to show the calender. I want to access First day and last day of the week of the date selected.

Here is what I have tried

```
     this.tv_date.setText( new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(monthName).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(""));
        tv_date.setHighlightColor(Color.CYAN);

        String str=mDay+"-"+mMonth+"-"+mYear;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        sdf.format(""+str); //here I am getting exception

        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

        int s=  cal.getFirstDayOfWeek();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "first day of the week : "+s, 1).show();
```

But I am getting "IllegalArguementException".
Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sdf.format(""+str);` - is wrong. You either need to pass a `Date` object to it, or else, change it to `sdf.parse(str);` to get a `Date` object from it.

**Edit:-** To get the first day of the week, do this.

```
String str=mDay+"-"+mMonth+"-"+mYear;
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date myDate = new Date();
try{
    myDate = sdf.parse(str);
}catch(ParseException pe){
    // Do Something
}
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.setTime(myDate);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);  
int s = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

Comment: thanks! But Toast is showing me 1 every time even if I select other date. how to get first day of the week.

Comment: Yeah Its working fine for current(March) month but for previous and next month its showing wrong values.

Comment: its working for all cases. I tested it before posting. Just now verified again for `13-02-2013` and got the output as `10`.

Comment: I dont know why I am still facing this problem. I have also tested it on diff avd 2.2. currently I am running this on 3.2. Nevertheless I gonna accept your answer :(

Comment: try to run this as a stand-alone java program and put loggers wherever needed. See what it displays. If its working fine there, double check with the values you're getting from your data picker in the android code.

Comment: Yeaah!!! It's working fine now for all cases.  Thank you so much @R.J! You helped me a lot by giving your valuable time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of calculating the first day of week.

```
private void firstDayOfThisWeek(){
 DateTime today = DateTime.today(TimeZone.getDefault()); 
 DateTime firstDayThisWeek = today; //start value 
 int todaysWeekday = today.getWeekDay();
 int SUNDAY = 1;
 if(todaysWeekday > SUNDAY){
   int numDaysFromSunday = todaysWeekday - SUNDAY;
   firstDayThisWeek = today.minusDays(numDaysFromSunday);
 }
 System.out.println("The first day of this week is : " + firstDayThisWeek);
}
```

Instead of assigning today you can assign any other day with exact format

Comment: but I guess, DateTime class is not in android library